# I got error when npm install -g solc

Tags: solc

I got error when try to install solc using

```
npm install -g solc
```

here is the error:

```
erfans-MacBook-Pro:01 erfanandesta$ npm uninstall -g solc
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/solc
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/solc/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/solc
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/solc'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/solc']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    "Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/solc'",
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/solc' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/erfanandesta/.npm/_logs/2018-12-06T07_44_32_823Z-debug.log
```

when i use `sudo npm install -g solc` it install successfully i now i got this error :

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:605
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './smtchecker.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:603:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:658:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/solc/solcjs:9:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:722:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:733:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a `solc` related error. Use below command instead:

```
sudo npm install -g solc
```

You need to provide sufficient permissions as you are installing it globally.

**EDIT1:**
Regarding the `smtchecker` error, it seems it is missing this file : https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js/blob/master/smtchecker.js

Put it in the right place in your `solcjs` package folder and it should be working.

Although this is a workaround not a regular solution because this seems a problem with `solc`. I have raised the issue regarding this, which can be followed here: https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js/issues/324

Comment: i update my question

Comment: That is a different question which looks related to your project structure. Should be asked separately.

Comment: I think it's not about my project because I dont have any yet.if you know the answer update it

Comment: Does this error appear while installing solc?

Comment: not exactly but after installing i want to test if it's installed successfully or not and I got this error

Comment: How you are testing it? Please add complete information in the question.

Comment: i just run `solcjs` and it should say that `no file provided` as I see in tutorials but i got that last error. I search in for .smtchecker and there is nothing to help

Comment: Try running `solcjs --help` once and let me know the result.

Comment: It returns the same error

Comment: Updated the answer regarding this

Comment: tnx it's working

Comment: I can also confirm that after I copy and pasted the file from GitHub it worked. However, this is *not* normal. Is there a problem with the `solc` repo?